Proving inequality regarding expected error involving covariance and its estimate.
Let $$ A =  \left( I - \frac{\Sigma \iota \iota'}{\iota' \Sigma \iota} \right)(\hat \Sigma \iota).$$
Where $\Sigma$ is the true $nxn$ covariance matrix of a random vector x that is normally distributed, $\hat \Sigma$ is an estimate for this covariance matrix, and $\iota$ is a vector of ones of size nx1.
The estimate can be the sample covariance or a Bayesian estimate using the sample covariance and a prior, or in general, a positive definite matrix.
I want to understand under what conditions A = 0 (as a vector). Ideally, in the case where $\hat \Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix or $\hat \Sigma = \Sigma + D$ where D is a positive definite matrix.
So far, I can show that if $\hat \Sigma = b \Sigma, b != 0$, then $A = 0$. Is this case an if and only if?
Alternatively, I would like to understand when
$$E[A'A] > 0$$ or $$E[A'\Sigma^{-1}A] > 0.$$
I would also appreciate guidance but would prefer an answer.

I will assume that $\hat\Sigma$ is the unbiased sample covariance matrix estimator obtained from an i.i.d. normal sample of size $T$. This means that $\hat\Sigma$ is Wishart-distributed: $$(T-1)\hat\Sigma\sim\mathcal{W}_N(T-1,\Sigma).$$ Let me also introduce the matrix $$B=I-\frac{\Sigma\iota\iota'}{\iota'\Sigma\iota},$$ so that we can write your matrix $A$ as $$A=B\hat\Sigma\iota.$$

When does $A=0$? Given that $\mathbb{E}[\hat\Sigma]=\Sigma$, it is easy to see that $\mathbb{E}[A]=0$. However, $\hat\Sigma$ being random, $A\neq0$ with probability one.

For what follows, I will use the result that if $X\sim\mathcal{W}_N(m,\Sigma)$, and $C$ is a symmetric matrix, then $\mathbb{E}[XCX]=m(m+1)\Sigma C\Sigma+m\hspace{0.03cm}\textrm{tr}(\Sigma C)\Sigma$.

When does $\mathbb{E}[A'A]>0$? Using the result above, we have $$\mathbb{E}[A'A]=\iota'\mathbb{E}[\hat\Sigma B^2\hat\Sigma]\iota=\frac{T(\iota'\Sigma B^2\Sigma\iota) +\textrm{tr}(\Sigma B^2)\iota'\Sigma\iota}{T-1}.$$ We can show that $$\iota'\Sigma B^2\Sigma\iota=\iota'\Sigma\iota-\iota'\Sigma^2\iota, \\ \textrm{tr}(\Sigma B^2)\iota'\Sigma\iota = \textrm{tr}(\Sigma)\iota'\Sigma\iota-\iota'\Sigma^2\iota.$$ Thus, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[A'A]=\frac{(T+\textrm{tr}(\Sigma))\iota'\Sigma\iota-(T+1)\iota'\Sigma^2\iota}{T-1},$$
and the condition $\mathbb{E}[A'A]>0$ becomes
$$(T+\textrm{tr}(\Sigma))\iota'\Sigma\iota>(T+1)\iota'\Sigma^2\iota,$$
which, for $T$ large enough, is approximately equivalent to $\iota'\Sigma\iota>\iota'\Sigma^2\iota$.

When does $\mathbb{E}[A'\Sigma^{-1}A]>0$? Using the result above, we have $$\mathbb{E}[A'\Sigma^{-1}A]=\iota'\mathbb{E}[\hat\Sigma B\Sigma^{-1}B\hat\Sigma]\iota=\frac{T(\iota'\Sigma B\Sigma^{-1}B\Sigma\iota)+\textrm{tr}(\Sigma B\Sigma^{-1}B)\iota'\Sigma\iota}{T-1}.$$ We can show that $$\iota'\Sigma B\Sigma^{-1}B\Sigma\iota=0, \\ \textrm{tr}(\Sigma B\Sigma^{-1}B)\iota'\Sigma\iota = \frac{(N-2)(\iota'\Sigma\iota)^2+N\iota'\Sigma^2\iota}{\iota'\Sigma\iota}.$$ Thus, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[A'\Sigma^{-1}A]=\frac{(N-2)(\iota'\Sigma\iota)^2+N\iota'\Sigma^2\iota}{(T-1)\iota'\Sigma\iota},$$ which means that $\mathbb{E}[A'\Sigma^{-1}A]>0$ if $\Sigma$ is positive definite and $N\geq2$.


